# Negate boolean variable in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Suppose I set the following variable in CMake:

```
set(foo TRUE)
```

Now, I want to define a `bar` variable with the opposite boolean value of `foo` (in other words: in this context, I want `bar` to be `FALSE`, or equivalent, like `false` or `0`). One way of completing this is:

```
if(foo)
    set(bar FALSE)
else()
    set(bar TRUE)
endif()
```

However, this is kinda verbose. **How can I accomplish the same thing in fewer lines**?

---

### Notes

I tried to use generator expressions, but they don't seem to work in the `set` command:

```
set(bar $<NOT:${foo}>)
```

Or even

```
set(bar $<NOT:foo>)
```

Won't produce the desired result.

Comment: Do you mind accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [no way to evaluate an expression](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2006-March/008755.html).

If you need it often, you can write a helper function to handle the inversion. The call signature is clumsy, because you have to pass the variable name and it's value.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(InvertFunction)

function (invertBoolean varName varValue)
  if(${varValue})
    set(${varName} false PARENT_SCOPE)
  else()
    set(${varName} true PARENT_SCOPE)
  endif()
endfunction()

set(foo true)
invertBoolean("foo" foo)
message("Invert foo: ${foo}")

set(bar false)
invertBoolean("bar" bar)
message("Invert bar: ${bar}")
```

Comment: Another implementation of a similar negate function in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lukka/3efc3772b4c87d350424209172f0599e)